# Why does the most visited thumbnails list in Chrome sometimes completely change?

Tags: google-chrome

I get pretty accustomed to the order of thumbnails in the [New Tab](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2918032?hl=en) page of Google Chrome. I am able to notice when the order changes or when thumbnails change. Sometimes the list ***drastically*** changes. Sites which are not in my top 8 will show up and the thumbnails of sites which are normally there might be different. But it only happens once. Next time I open a new tab the normal order is restored.

Here is an intentionally blurred screenshot of the phenomena. On the left is the normal New Tab page. On the rigth is the unusual new tab page that appears occasionally. You can see that the two lists are very different.

[image]

I can't figure out what triggers this. The best guess I have is Google running an experiment to see how much I depend on the list.

What is happening? Is there a way to turn off this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* there is some algorithm behind the thumbnails.  It combines most visited and most active over time.  I do occasionally see a site I do not visit often over time, but have visited a bunch recently pop in the list.